# use a signal between 2 classes Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

I have a MainWindow class which contain a QComboBox and a widget which is from another class. This second class contain a QCheckBox and a QComboBox. I want to use a signal to change the checkState of my QCheckBox and the string displayed in my QComboBox from my widget class when the string displayed in my QComboBox from my MainWindow has changed.

But I don't really understand which form my signal must have and how I can use it in my widget class.

MainWindow.h :

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QComboBox>

#include "devices_left_widget.h"

#define STRING_DEVICE1 "DEVICE1"
#define STRING_DEFAULT ""

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

signals:

public slots:
    void carte_OK();

protected:
    QComboBox* carte_type_combo_box;

    devices_left_widget* left_widget;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

device_left_widget.h :

```cpp
#ifndef DEVICE_LEFT_WIDGET_H
#define DEVICE_LEFT_WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QComboBox>

#define STRING_DEVICE1 "DEVICE1"
#define STRING_DEFAULT ""

    class device_left_widget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit device_left_widget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    QGridLayout* main_grid_layout;

    QCheckBox* device_checkbox;

    QComboBox* device_type_combo_box;
};

#endif // DEVICES_LEFT_WIDGET_H
```

Comment: Could you please share a bit of code ?

Comment: Yeah I've edit my post if you want to see

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (_i.e._ regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call your widget's name `container`. We want to connect QComboBox's `currentTextChanged(const QString &text)` signal to the widget, so we create a slot that corresponds to the signal, let it be `chosenTextChanged(const QString& text)`. We connect them inside `MainWindow` constructor:

```
    connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(const QString &)),
            ui->container, SLOT(chosenTextChanged(const QString &)));
```

And inside your container class, define the slot as public:

```
public slots:
    void chosenTextChanged(const QString &text) {
        //change your QCheckBox's state and
        //change your QComboBox's text
}
```

Comment: My eyes start bleeding everytime I see the legacy old style of connections from Qt4.

Comment: I am stuck with that at work since I have large (several hundred thousand lines of code) projects that still use Qt4 because of compatibility with all third party libraries. For one of them it would take over a half of a man year to port because of changed features in the third party libs so we have not done so.